# find numpy rows that are the same

Tags: numpy, rows

I have a numpy array

How can I find which of them are the same and how many times appear in the matrix?
thanks
dummy example:

```
A=np.array([[0, 1, 0, 1],[0, 0, 0, 0],[0, 1, 1, 1],[0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`numpy.unique`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) with `axis=0` and `return_counts=True`:

```
np.unique(A, axis=0, return_counts=True)
```

Output:

```
(array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 1],
        [0, 1, 1, 1]]),
 array([2, 1, 1]))
```

Comment: As an aside, If the number of rows is substantially lager than number of columns, `pandas.DataFrame.value_counts` can be faster as it avoids sorting rows.

Comment: i tried it, it works!! thank you very much!!